# 404 Error handling/htaccess for subdomains

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, error-handling, http-status-code-404

I would like to have a `404` error page. This will be in the root direction.

The problem I have is that in my `.htaccess` I have set the following relative path:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

This works for the domain but does not work for subdomains. At the moment the `404.php` just echoes the requested `URL` by using and echoing

```
$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
```

The problem is that when causing an `404` error in a subdomain the `404.php` could not be found and a default message from the server will be displayed.

So I also tried to use absolute path settings but this causes the failure that an internal redirect takes place and the `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]`will be empty respectively it will be echoed just `404.php`.

If there is someone who could give me hints on how to fetch this I really would appreciate.

Thanks alot.

Comment: `/404.php` is an absolute path not a relative one. `404.php` would be a relative path. `http://www.example.com/404.php` would be a absolute url and `//www.example.com/404.php` would be a (protocol) relative url.

Comment: Make sure your customized error page `/404.php` has the content size greater than 512 bytes. Many browsers like IE, Chrome etc don't show your customized page if content length of your custom 404 page is less than 512.